# Build and deploy packaged RoR application on Windows machine that got no Internet access

Tags: ruby, bitnami, ruby-on-rails-5

Is it possible and if so what is the best way to do it? I heard a friend talking about bitnami and so  on. Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save you image to tar and copy with USB and loaded it back.

Save your mage: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

```
docker save image_name > filename.tar
```

Load image from Tar(No internet access required): 
 https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/#examples

```
docker load --input filename.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bitnami Ruby stack https://bitnami.com/stack/ruby. The only moment where you may require internet is for downloading the gems that your application may require. After that, you should be able to work in your local environment without issues. Another alternative is to download the gems from another machine and install it in your local system.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to build a RoR application without internet access but it is not possible to deploy it. You could, however, run a hotspot off of a phone or something purely for deployments.